# Public function accessible at design time but inaccessible at runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an aspx file in vb.net which has a public function called GetOldestYear(string) which VisualStudio shows as accessible, does not throw any error messages and builds successfully.  When I debug it hits the line of code which calls the shared function and fails:

Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'GetOldestYear' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

The public function is in a public module (I have also tried a shared class with the same issue)

```
Public Module Module1
   Public Function GetOldestYear(Query As String) As Integer
      ...
   End Function
End Module
```

Then I call from my page load event in my aspx.vb file

`Dim oldestYear As Integer = GetOldestYear("select top 1 Year from table")`

How can the function be accessible at design time but not at runtime?  This will likely be something obvious that I've missed but I just can't see it!

Comment: Have you tried `Module1.GetOldestYear("select top 1 Year from table")` instead? (I know it says you don't need the `Module1`.) Also, "Build"->"Clean solution" then build it again. And restart IIS. Do any other Subs/Functions in Module1 work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a project Asp.NET you need to create a folder in the root project path named “App_Code” and put there your “Module1.vb”
All the code into this folder is going to be compiled in a .dll and is accessible in all your Web app.
Also you need to be sure the building action for your “Module1” is “Build” and not “Content”.
GO to module prorperties (Selct "Module1.vb" item → Right click on mouse → Properties) and go to Building Action and change to "Build"

[image]