# vb.net public function works in some aspx pages but not others. Calls are the same

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, public

I have a public function in a vb module which works in many aspx pages.  However, in one page, I get an error message that I included below.

I tried putting the function in the base page and in the master page.  Neither helped.

> C:\Users\jb_mo\OneDrive\CCFRW19\CCFRW19\EventRegister.aspx.vb(8): error BC30451: 'GetConnectionStringM' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: You might have the same issue, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646445/public-function-accessible-at-design-time-but-inaccessible-at-runtime/58647853#58647853

Comment: Can you please double check the ConnectionString in the web.config and confirm that one with the name "GetConnectionStringM" exists. Perhaps there's a typo in there, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Moving the module to App_code solved my problem.  One small  note, the build action in VS 2019 doesn't all "Build".  I used Compile instead and it worked fine.